# Can I work in Visual Studio 2019 and gfortran (gcc) compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there any approach to work on visual studio with gfortran?
I have Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 and gcc 7 installed using Cygwin.

Comment: Can you please provide an elaborate instructions as I am new to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume Cygwin installation path is `D:\Cygwin` and `gcc-fortran` package is already installed in Cygwin.

- Add the Cygwin installation folder in `%PATH%` environment variable in Control Panel.
- Create `HelloWorld.f90` file in a folder:

```
program hello
print *,"Hello World!"
end program hello
```

- Open that folder in VSCode.
- Go to Terminal > Configure Tasks > Create task.json file from template > Others.
- VSCode will automatically create and open a `tasks.json` file in `.vscode` folder.
- Add this JSON code:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "D:\\Cygwin\\bin\\gfortran.exe",
            "args": [
                "HelloWorld.f90"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- Add other required parameters in `args` field in the above JSON file.
- Go to Terminal > Run Build Task or press Ctrl+Shift+B to build it. Click on build.

The gfortran path will be different if different package is installed. Optionally, [fortran extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=fortran&target=VSCode) can be downloaded from Visual Studio MarketPlace for syntax highlighting. For further information, read [tasks in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a fortran expert. So, my procedure may not be perfect.