# Making Visual Studio 2019 a Fortran IDE

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to know how I can tune **Visual Studio 2019** to have a fully featured modern Fortran IDE for **gfortran**.

This would include:

- one click compilation
- debuging
- auto-completion

If you also known any other interesting feature I would be interested.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I work in Visual Studio 2019 and gfortran (gcc) compiler?](https://superuser.com/questions/1434539/can-i-work-in-visual-studio-2019-and-gfortran-gcc-compiler)

Comment: It is for Visual Studio Code so sadly the answer is no.

Comment: Try [this](https://blog.kitware.com/fortran-for-cc-developers-made-easier-with-cmake/).

Comment: @harrymc.. NICE.. I had given up finding this guy a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Gfortran is found in MinGW, so not directly using Windows API, which complicates
using it from Visual Studio.

See the following article for a detailed description of the process using CMake:
[Fortran for C/C++ developers made easier with CMake](https://blog.kitware.com/fortran-for-cc-developers-made-easier-with-cmake/).

This involves:

- Creating Visual Studio `.lib` files from MinGW gfortran
- Including in the project the module `CMakeAddFortranSubdirectory.cmake`
- Automatically detect the Fortran runtime library and use it
- Automatically Determine Symbol Mangling Used by Fortran Compiler